# Photos: Delete Photo with Command or Option-Command

Tags: keyboard, photos.app, high-sierra

In Photos 3.0 (from macOS 10.13 High Sierra) there is apparently two distinct ways to delete photos.

Delete by holding <kbd>Command</kbd> in the menu, or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (<kbd>⌘⌫</kbd>).

[image: Delete with Command]

Or delete by holding <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd> in the menu or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (<kbd>⌥⌘⌫</kbd>).

[image: Delete with Option-Command]

What is the difference?

If there is no difference, why is there two different keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Interesting question, I think it's for convenience.

Comment: Oh, right. That does not make a difference to the menu user ("Duplicate Photo" is still there regardless of how many modifier keys are held down), but that does make a difference to the keyboard user.

Comment: In Finder, we see cmd+delete as the shortcut to delete files. But in photos and mail, delete itself seems enough. But for UI consistency, cmd+delete seems to be a good choice. 

In macOS Mojave, the number of keys have been reduced to 1 to delete a photo or a mail.